# CIELab Colorspace conversion

Tags: c++, c, colors, color-space

Is there a canonical colorspace conversion library? I can't find any pre-existing solutions. Is CIELab conversion is too obscure?

Comment: which colourspace do you want to convert to/from? CIE XYZ? sRGB? I can't imagine this is too obscure for a library, but it might be too simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not obscure, I have done it myself recently from RGB to CIELAB.
Look at the source of OpenCV there is a lot of color convesrion functions. 
File is: ../src/cv/cvcolor.cpp
Have a look at the function icvBGRx2Lab_32f_CnC3R for example. This is probably what are you looking for.