# Find the nearest sRGB-representable color to a given CIEL*a*b* color

Tags: colors

I have a color specified in the [CIE L*a*b*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space) color space which is outside the range that standard [sRGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB_color_space) monitors can display. I'd like to display an approximation of the given color (at the same luminance/L value as specified), but the maths is pretty gnarly and involves finding intersections between piecewise functions and so on.

Is there any reference code for this, or should I forge ahead with the maths?

To clarify: given a point `a,b` that is NOT within the shape below, I would like to find the nearest `a,b` that IS within the shape.

[image: Lab color space]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using mat lab:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24009

Also there is a thread on the reverse function [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205908/rgb-to-cielab-conversion) that mentions a [site that has many programming examples for the conversion](http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH).

You could combine "CIE-L*ab —> XYZ" and the "XYZ —> RGB" conversion.

---

**UPDATE:**

I just found this:
http://www.cs.washington.edu/research/imagedatabase/summerproject/2004/eye/src/yi/iu/processor/color/CIELab.java

But I couldn't find out what licence it uses, so maybe you should contact the author, if you are using it.

Comment: Converting between the colors is fine; what I'm looking for is a way to find the closest point within [this shape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Lab_color_space.png) to some `a,b` which is outsidce that shape.