# Converting pixel RGB values to CIELAB colorspace and fetching them OpenGL GLSL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, libtorch

I'm experimenting on automatic colorization of 3D Scenes in image space with libtorch. The model input is the L component of an image and predicts the AB values to colorize it.

I am wondering what is the most efficient method of converting the RGB values of the pixels to CIELAB and then fetch them to do the predictions?

Comment: Are you searching for functions in C++ to perform such conversions? You could take a look at http://www.easyrgb.com/en/math.php as suggested by this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205908/rgb-to-cielab-conversion. You could quickly write C++ code based on the pseudo code given in that site. I have implemented C++ functions based on that site and it worked for me.

Comment: LAB<->RGB is going to be negligible compared to the amount of work done in those models.